# How to retrofit the following Mongoose aggregation built on MongoDB 4.0 to work on 3.6?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

A table-query aggregation based on a custom JSON specification that defines things like what documents to populate was coded without realizing our MongoDB provider mlab doesn't support the latest and greatest (i.e. 4.0+).  We probably won't be able to upgrade to 4.0 before October when mlab migrates to MongoDB Atlas, so I am looking at retrofitting this code.

So far, I know that the reference to $toObjectId throws an error.  That is in the part that populates related documents by id kind of like your average data framework (and I realize I should be using something like KeystoneJS but I am new to Full-stack development and rolling my own thing might be a good way to gain a deep understanding).  Could anyone lend a hand and point out any other 4.0+ features this code is using and ideas for workarounds/alternatives that would work on 3.6?

```
let models = require('../../server/models.js');


// filter: optional mongo filter object
// search: optional seearch string
// columns: optional array
module.exports.search = function( model, page, perPage, callback, sort, filter, search, columns, populate ) {
    perPage = ( perPage * 1 ) || 100;

    let aggregate = [];
    let project = {};

    let match = {};

    console.log( model.modelName, page, perPage, sort, filter, search, columns, populate );

    if ( filter == null && ( search !== "false" && search.length > 0 ) ) {
        match = Object.assign( match,{ $text: { $search: search } } );
        aggregate.push( { $match: match } );
    }

    for( let column of columns ) {
        if( ! column ) continue;
        if( column.indexOf('.') >= 0 ) {
            project[column.split('.')[0]] = "$"+column.split('.')[0];
        } else {
            project[column] = "$"+column;
        }
    }
    aggregate.push( {$project:project} );



    if ( filter !== null   &&   ! ( sea if ( populate ) {
        for( let path of populate ) {
            aggregate.push( { $addFields: { [ path.path ]: { $toObjectId: "$" + path.path } } } );
            aggregate.push(
                { $lookup: {
                        from: path.model,
                        localField: path.path,
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: path.path,
                    } } );
            aggregate.push( { $unwind: "$" + path.path }, );
        }
    }rch !== "false" && search.length > 0 ) ) {
        for( let k of Object.keys( filter ) ) {
            // fix up filters on boolean-type columns:
            if ( filter[k] === 'true') filter[k] = true;
            if ( filter[k] === 'false') filter[k] = false;
        }
        match = Object.assign( match, filter );
        aggregate.push( { $match: match } );
    }

    if ( sort ) aggregate.push( { $sort: sort } );

    let skip = ( ( page - 1 ) * perPage );
    let limit = ( perPage );

    model.aggregate( aggregate )
        .group( { _id: null, rows: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, total: {$sum:1} } )
        .project( { rows:  { $slice: [ "$rows", skip, limit ] } , total: "$total" } )
        .exec( ( err, response ) => {
            if( err ) {
                console.log( err );
            }
            // console.log( "AGGREGATE RESULT: ", response );
            callback( err, response ? response[ 0 ] : { total: 0, rows: [] } );
            // callback( err, { total: 50, rows: response } );
        } );

};
```

#### Here is an example of a table specification:

```
        /* Resources */
        '/admin/resources': {
            model: "Resources",
            populate: [
                { path:'type', model:'resourcetypes', },
            ],
            columns: [
                { field:'_id', label:'ID', },
                { field:'name', sortable: true, searchable: true, },
                { field:'slug', sortable: true, searchable: true, },
                { field:'type.name', sortable: true, searchable: true, label:'Type', },
                { type:'button', action:'delete', },
            ],
            detail: {
                fields: [
                    { field:'name', required:true },
                    { field:'slug', required:true },
                ]
            }
        },
```